# Spring Boot Data Redis Stream consume messages in Batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, redis-streams

I am trying to consume messages from Redis Stream in Batch using *Imperative StreamMessageListenerContainer* of Spring Boot Data Redis.

But this have method signature of 'MapRecord<String, String, String> message'

How to use List or Set for this. I added the Batch size 3 in Subscription .

`.batchSize(3)`

Subscription Code

```
public Subscription subscribeToEvents(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) throws InterruptedException {


    StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, MapRecord<String, Object, Object>> listenerContainer =
            StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(Objects.requireNonNull(redisConnectionFactory),
                    StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions.builder()
                            .hashKeySerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(String.class))
                            .hashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class))
                            .pollTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                            .batchSize(3)
                            .build());

    StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest<String> streamReadRequest =
            StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest
                    .builder(StreamOffset.create(redisStreamName, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()))
                    .consumer(Consumer.from(consumerGroup, redisStreamName))
                    .cancelOnError(ex -> false)
                  
                    .autoAcknowledge(false)
                    .build();

    Subscription subscription = listenerContainer.register(streamReadRequest, streamListener2);

    listenerContainer.start();
    LOGGER.info("Registered subscriber for stream key: {} with consumer group: {} & consumer name: {}", redisStreamName, consumerGroup);
    return subscription;
}
```

StreamListener Code

```
public class RedisStreamListener2 implements StreamListener<String, MapRecord<String, Object, Object>> {

    @Value("${redis-stream-name2}")
    private String redisStreamName;

    @Value("${redis-stream-consumer2}")
    private String consumerGroup;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisStreamListener2.class);

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(MapRecord<String, Object, Object> message) {
        LOG.debug(" - message Received from Redis :");
        String stream = message.getStream();
        RecordId id = message.getId();
        String data=  (String)message.getValue().get("testdata");
        try {
            EventEFRModel eventEFRModel = CommonUtils.readStringToObject(data,EventEFRModel.class);
            LOG.debug(" - consumed data:" +eventModel);
          

           acknowledgeAndDeleteRecord(stream,stream,id);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

How ever with Redis template archive this But need to add Scheduler to listen the messages for infinity times.

```
   List<MapRecord<String, Object, Object>> messages = redisTemplate.opsForStream().read(Consumer.from(consumerGroup, redisStreamName)
            , StreamReadOptions.empty().autoAcknowledge().count(2),
            StreamOffset.create(redisStreamName, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()));
```

Is It even Possible in Spring Boot or I Miss understood the **batch size** value  in Subscription .

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand the `batchSize` that you can set on the listening container is the number of messages specified as the COUNT in the underlying [XREADGROUP](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup/) command. Increasing this batch size reduces the number of Redis calls your app needs to make if your stream is large or has a high throughput.

It doesn't really make sense why we can't then consume this as a list in the consumer `onMessage()` but maybe they'll add that functionality someday. What you can do if you're wanting to process messages in a batch (if you're single-threaded) is to simply add the messages to an instance variable list then process the list when it reaches the `batchSize`.

```java
...
private List<MapRecord<String, Object, Object>> messageBatch = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onMessage(MapRecord<String, Object, Object> message) {
  messageBatch.add(message);
  if(messageBatch.size() >= batchSize){
    processBatch();
    messageBatch.clear();
  }
}

private void processBatch(){
  // do stuff over entire batch like pipelined Redis calls, etc
}
...
```

If you have multiple subscriptions (threads) registered for the consumer which are all using the same `StreamListener` class then this approach won't work since it's not thread safe. In this case you could try using something like a ThreadLocal list so each consumer thread has their own batch.